# How to add ComboBoxColumn to the data table and not to the Datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a data table that is serializable. I wanted to add a comboboxcolumn to the datagridview and used `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();` but then I am not able to serialize the new bind because I'm trying to serialize the datagridview and not data table which is impossible. So I want to try if there's any way to add combobox column to data table and not to datagridview so that I'm able to serialize.

Hope I make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Well it doesn't make sense :). Serialization is used to convert data to a form(Xml or Binary etc), which can be used for data flow between different systems. Combo Box is not data. You can't serialize Windows Form Control.

If you are willing to show a collection of items (Combo Box's data) in your serialized XML or binary, you need to add a collection in your data table. The best approach will be to create a class which carries all items of your table. Then Create a property in your class which carries all the items of dropdown. Then serialize that class.

**Edit after our discussion in Comments**

So you can add a collection in DataTable after you data. Though its doesn't seem like a very performance oriented solution.. so either you can optimize it or may be move to a class. Below is code where I am able to inject a Collection in data table and its serialize very well.

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source={yourdbserver};Initial Catalog=StudentsEnrolment;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("select * from students"))
    {
        command.Connection = sqlConnection;
        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            dataAdapter.Fill(0, 10, table);
            table.TableName = "Students";

            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TestingCollection", typeof(List<string>)));

            var testingstring = new List<string>() { "String 1", "string 2", "string 3" };
            foreach(DataRow datarow in table.Rows)
            {
                datarow.SetField("TestingCollection", testingstring);
            }
            var xmlWriter = new StringWriter();
            table.WriteXml(xmlWriter);
            Console.WriteLine(xmlWriter);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**This is how serialized XML looks after this**

```
<DocumentElement>
  <Students>
    <StudendId>5</StudendId>
    <First_x0020_Name>VSK</First_x0020_Name>
    <Last_x0020_Name>sas</Last_x0020_Name>
    <Middle_x0020_Name>sas</Middle_x0020_Name>
    <Email>v@test.com</Email>
    <Cellphone>+255345345334</Cellphone>
    <TelePhone>3454354334</TelePhone>
    <CourseId>1001</CourseId>
    <TestingCollection xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
      <string>String 1</string>
      <string>string 2</string>
      <string>string 3</string>
    </TestingCollection>
  </Students>
  <Students>
    <StudendId>6</StudendId>
    <First_x0020_Name>Agrerer</First_x0020_Name>
    <Last_x0020_Name>sas</Last_x0020_Name>
    <Middle_x0020_Name>sas</Middle_x0020_Name>
    <Email>v@test.com</Email>
    <Cellphone>+255345345334</Cellphone>
    <TelePhone>3454354334</TelePhone>
    <TestingCollection xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
      <string>String 1</string>
      <string>string 2</string>
      <string>string 3</string>
    </TestingCollection>
  </Students>
  <Students>
    <StudendId>7</StudendId>
    <First_x0020_Name>Scott</First_x0020_Name>
    <Last_x0020_Name>sas</Last_x0020_Name>
    <Middle_x0020_Name>sas</Middle_x0020_Name>
    <Email>abc@test.com</Email>
    <Cellphone>+255345345334</Cellphone>
    <TelePhone>3454354334</TelePhone>
    <TestingCollection xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
      <string>String 1</string>
      <string>string 2</string>
      <string>string 3</string>
    </TestingCollection>
  </Students>
  <Students>
    <StudendId>8</StudendId>
    <First_x0020_Name>AMR/JJohnson</First_x0020_Name>
    <Last_x0020_Name>asd</Last_x0020_Name>
    <Middle_x0020_Name>asd</Middle_x0020_Name>
    <Email>
      asd
    </Email>
    <Cellphone>ads</Cellphone>
    <TelePhone>asd</TelePhone>
    <TestingCollection xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
      <string>String 1</string>
      <string>string 2</string>
      <string>string 3</string>
    </TestingCollection>
  </Students>
</DocumentElement>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Gaurav. What you said absolutely makes sense but my data table is variable. Too variable that its difficult to mention all the items of table in the class. 

And when it comes to performance, I find it good to serialize with respective to object of the data table rather doing with respective to class.

Comment: HI Jashwanth, In that case I will try adding a new Column to data table. Trying to add a new collection to the column (may be a nested Data Table) in that column. I will try writing some code to test that.

Comment: What doesn't work? Please tell me error. and show me your code.